# jQuery Find all rows that checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a checkbox .
I need to know which table rows was checked,
after clicking the Update button.

```
 <div id='ggg' style="position:absolute; bottom:0px" id=>

    <table class="display" id="poll">
    <th>Polling</th>
            <th>rrd</th>
<tr>
  <td>ping</td>
  <td>10.rrd</td>   
<td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked"/> 
        </td>  
  </tr>
<tr>
  <td>snmp</td>
  <td>11.rrd</td>   
<td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="myTextEditBox" value="checked" /> 
        </td>  
</tr>
</table>
<form>
<input type='button' id='update' value='update'>
</form>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want to highlight tr or td?

Comment: No, I want to get the <tr> text value

Comment: including td or all td's text only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#update").click(function () {
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        alert($(this).closest("tr").text());
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/80/)**

**Edit**

```
$("#update").click(function () {
    $("#poll").find('input:checked').each(function () {
        alert($(this).closest("tr").text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('#update').on('click',function(){
    $('#poll').find('input:checked').closest('tr').css('background','green');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/45Z98/)

Comment: @user3485339 `var text =  $('#poll').find('input:checked').closest('tr').text()`  Check this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/45Z98/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:checked` selector to get checked checkbox along with `.closest(tr)` to get row. Try this:

```
checkedrows = $('input:checked').closest('tr');
```

Comment: I did not understand exactly how to use it

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

> if you want to highlight to tr:

```
$('#update').on('click',function(){
    $(':checked').parents('tr').css('background','#ff0');
});
```

> if you want to highlight to td:

```
$('#update').on('click',function(){
    $(':checked').parent().css('background','#ff0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#update').click(function() {
 var checkboxes = $('#poll').find('input:checked').closest('tr');
 // this will give you which table rows was checked    
});
```